# spstack, ptrace stopped a process

Tags: performance, strace, trap

My server is busy with sys CPU, so I used pstrace to trace it but no output, so I cancel the command inside putty, and then use pstack to trace it again, but no result return either and I closed the putty ssh session to kill the trace. But now find the process is hang, when using "ps aux", the status is T1 which means it stopped by traced.

meaning of T is as below, but I don't know the status of T1

T:    Stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being
            traced.

So why it could stop the process after I exit the putty ssh. And how to restart the stopped process?

Comment: What is the operating system?

Comment: it's Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

Comment: Do `grep State: /proc/the-pid/status`. Is it `State: T (stopped)` or `State: t (tracing stop)` ?

Comment: We killed that process since time is urgent to do so. So I can't know the real status using your command. But that command looks good